# Button not showing in nslocalnotification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have written the following code for displaying local notifications.However,a button is not showing up on the notifications when i receive them.Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?
I have written the following piece of code in application did enter background event.

```
UILocalNotification *local=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
    local.fireDate=alertTime;
    local.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    local.alertBody=@"Hello this is a local notif";
    local.alertAction=@"Show";
    local.repeatInterval=0;
    local.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
    local.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    UIApplication *abc=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [abc scheduleLocalNotification:local];
```

Comment: Have you written - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification function in your app delegate class?

Comment: wt is ur problem..??notification is not received or badge number is not shown ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your code in AppDelegate.m File in below method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Show", nil];
        [alert show];
                [alert release];
    }
}
```